# Passing in an element in an array as a pointer in a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

I am trying to pass in an argument as a pointer through pthread_create.

```
typedef struct {
    int input;
    int threadNum;
} ARGS;

ARGS argument16[16];
for (x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    printf("pthread16_created: %d\n", x);
    argument16[x].threadNum = 16;
    argument16[x].input = x % 4;
    pthread_create(&(threads16[x]), NULL, funct, argument16[x]);
}
```

This is giving me 
    error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘pthread_create’

How do I pass in a ARG type pointer in a array of ARGS? I can't seem to figure it out. I know arrays are already a pointer, but not sure how to pointer to a certain element in the array.
Thank you

Comment: `&argument16[x]` In other words, you want to pass the **address of** the element, not the element itself.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final argument to `pthread_create()` is a pointer to void so an address typecast to `void *` is expected. So, like commenter said, the address of argument16[x] rather than the value which is what you passed. Otherwise known as rvalue.

Inside the thread function, you want a pointer of correct type so:

```
ARGS * ptr  = (   ARGS *  ) arg;
```

Is the expected way to type cast back.

If you aren't sure in the future use a pointer to same type and increment it per loop then pass by lvalue.